# Pandas doesn't work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio

I have a simple code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data_1.csv")
data.describe()
```

Problem is that when I run the code in VS Code I don't get any output, but when I run it in cmd everything works fine. What might be the problem?

Comment: I'll bet if you `print(data.describe())` it will show up in the terminal.  Those results are going somewhere, just not to wherever it is you're looking.

Comment: It might be that `print(data..)` is what is actually missing. If you want to have easier debugging/running you would need to follow [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations) steps to create a launch configuration that actually calls your python script. Please make sure as well that your terminal is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this step:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("data_1.csv")
data.describe()
print(data.describe())
```